# How to solve Cross-Origin Read Blocking error display on console?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please guide me.  how can i resolve this error responding on console,i am trying to run my script but the script is not working and getting this error on console of browser.

**This is the javascript what i am trying to run:**

`Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://profreehost.com/404/index.php with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should tell your server to allow the request by setting header. 
If you want to allow for only that PHP file, Add this line on top of your PHP file.

`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

If you want to allow for all resources, Add this line in your root `.htaccess` file.

`<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>`

Comment: And if you don't have access to the server, there is nothing you can do from the user perspective. Only chance is to build own backend that will automatically redirect request to the service and add Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the response.

Comment: @PatrikValkovič Yes.... **Tahridabbas This is a secury header. If this is your server or your backend. If this is a third-party URL, You can't. They don't want to allow anyone to access their resource.

Comment: Can you please show your error meassage. show your console.

Comment: Where did you put? You sould put on the file which you are tring to access from `https://profreehost.com`. For example if you want to connect `https://profreehost.com\profile.php` you should add that line in `https://profreehost.com\profile.php` file

Comment: yes i put on the top which i am trying to access from suppose i am browsing `index.php` and i put this line of code `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` as you told at the top whoever same error occurring.

Comment: please check above i added a image there.

Comment: Bro this is a Response MIME type Error. Please check the MIME type on response. in your browser Network tab

Comment: showing one `image.php` failed to load response data is this the problem?

Comment: Actually if the response MIME type is "application/json" but your request asks as "text/html" then your browser detects the MIME types are not matching, And it blocks the response. So you find the MIME of response, Then set the MIME type in request.

Comment: Thank you very much - in my case setting the Access Control header didn't work because the file was a remote pdf, however addding the lines to .htaccess did the trick.